# How to send a JSON object to a server in iOS using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I've put some data in a dictionary following the rules of `NSJSONSerialization` and I've retrieved my `JSONString`. How can I send this JSON object via `AFNetworking` to a server?

I need to pass some info from a form like name, surname, some numbers and send it to a server.
Is that possible?

Comment: the problem is that i found afjsonrequestoperation to receive answers from  the server but i don't know how to send data to the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AFNetworking` has built in ability to do a post.  Here is a tutorial with the details.

http://samwize.com/2012/10/25/simple-get-post-afnetworking/